# Nested routes do not work (react router v6)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

after browsing for a while on the internet I could not figure out why my nested routes do not work.

```
index.js
<BrowserRouter>
   12             <Navbar />
   13             <App />
   14         </BrowserRouter>
```

```
   App.js
   <>
   <Routes>
                   <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
                      <Route path="auth" element={<AuthApp />} />
                   </Route>
    </Routes>
    <Outlet />
   </>
```

```
      authApp.js
    6 const AuthApp = () => {
    7     return (
    8         <>
    9             <Routes>
   10                 <Route path="login" element={<LoginRoute />} />
   11                 <Route path="register" element={<RegisterRoute />} />
   12             </Routes>
   13             <Outlet />
   14         </>
   15     );
>> 16 }
```

LoginRoute, Home and RegisterRoute are very simple elements that for now should just display an h1. The problem is that /auth/login and /auth/register do not work. The links should be correct (I also tried manually to enter the url)

```
<nav style={navStyle}>
               <CustomNavLink to="/" routeName="Home" />
               <CustomNavLink to="/auth/login" routeName="Login" />
               <CustomNavLink to="/auth/register" routeName="Register" />
</nav>
```

Could someone spot the problem? Thank you in advance.
Additional question: Everytime I hit the login and register links I seem to get two hits.
This is the output I see in the console:

```
No routes matched location "/auth/login" 
No routes matched location "/auth/login"
```

Could someone explain this as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is because nested routes are not the same thing as descendent routes.

### Nested Routes:

Nested routes are `Route` components directly ***nested*** in another `Route` component. The parent `Route` component's `element` component needs to render an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their `element` content into for display when matched.

App

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
  <Route path="auth" element={<AuthApp />} />
</Route>
```

### Descendent Routes:

Descendent routes are routes that are rendered by *some* descendent component. These necessarily need to be rendered into a `Routes` component to handle further route matching and rendering.

AuthApp

```
const AuthApp = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginRoute />} />
        <Route path="register" element={<RegisterRoute />} />
      </Routes>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

In order for descendent routes to be able to still be matched the parent route needs to specify the trailing wildcard `"*"` matcher to its path. In this case, it is the `"/auth"` path. Update the parent route to `"/auth/*"` to allow descendent routes to also be matched and rendered.

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
  <Route path="auth/*" element={<AuthApp />} />
</Route>
```

For more information see [How do I nest routes deep in the tree](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/faq#how-do-i-nest-routes-deep-in-the-tree)

Comment: Thank you very much Drew I discovered it messing a little bit with the path.

Comment: @greatcoconut Welcome. I saw your comment in the other answer and saw that you called it a hack so it seemed there was some confusion on nomenclature and behavior. It's not a hack, but the intended syntax. Sorry, I wasn't able to find the correct doc page when I answered, but I've added this link to my answer which helps explain descendent routes: https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/faq#how-do-i-nest-routes-deep-in-the-tree.

Comment: Yeah Thank You very much, I definitely did not know why it worked nor the correct nomenclature. Definitely very helpful. Thanks for the link as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you maintain the route in only one file and `<Outlet />` put it inside your home component pls try this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-sknwsn?file=/src/App.js).

`index.js`

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Navbar />
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

`App.js` you don't need to create

```
<>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
      <Route path="auth">
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginRoute />} />
        <Route path="register" element={<RegisterRoute />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</>
```

`Home.js`

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```

`Navbar.js`

```
<nav style={navStyle}>
  <CustomNavLink to="/" routeName="Home" />
  <CustomNavLink to="/auth/login" routeName="Login" />
  <CustomNavLink to="/auth/register" routeName="Register" />
</nav>
```

Comment: I found a hack to use my version: <Route path="auth/*" ...

Comment: yes, it also works but I suggest you maintain the route in only one file.